# How to Split up sass file

Tags: html, css, sass, lesscss-resources

Lets say for example that I have HTML file with ,  and , how can I split up my css file into multiple files with each file containing styling for each of the tags. In other words, can I have header.scss, main.scss and footer.scss files all transpiling to a styles.css file? How can I do that? I don't want to have a long styles.css file that may become very difficult to maintain in the future.

I have tried wrapping the styles for the  and using the @use to bring it into the styles.scss file but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your file names:`_header.scss, _main.scss and _footer.scss`

You can import them all in a `style.scss`:

```
@import './header';
@import './main';
@import './footer';
```

and compile that into a css file containing all the scss files in one